# Why the difference in size when declaring a string in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I should know this, but I don't and I think its probably a major gap in my foundation knowledge so I thought I should ask the experts.

Given:

```
 char s1[] = { 'M', 'y', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'd' };
 char s2[] = "MyWord";

cout << strlen(s1)<<endl;
cout << strlen(s2)<<endl;

cout << sizeof(s1)<<endl;
cout << sizeof(s2)<<endl;
```

Why when declared as `s1` is the `strlen` 9 but when declared as `s2` is is 6? Where does the extra 3 come from, it it the lack of a null terminating character?

And I understand that `sizeof(s2)` is 1 byte larger than `sizeof(s2)` because s2 will have the null character automatically added?

Please be gentle, TIA!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char s2[] = "MyWord";` Auto adds the null terminator because of the "" declaration.

`s1` declaration does not. When you do a `strlen` on `s1` and it comes out to 9 it is because it eventually ran into a \0 and stopped. `s1` shouldn't be used with strlen since it is not null terminated. strlen on s1 could have been 1,000. If you turn on memory violation detection strlen of s1 would crash.

Answer (score 7):

The first one lacks the implicit `\0` terminator present in the second. Thus:

- The first is `1` less than the second, memory-wise
- Doing `strlen` on the first is undefined behavior (since it lacks the terminator)

Comment: Hey, does the size of s2 implies that the terminating character ***\0*** is one byte? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in C and C++ a `char` is always 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

Lack of terminating null character as you say.

When the `strlen` function is called on `s1`, it counts the characters until it finds a terminating `'\0'`.  You may have different result depending on how your memory is initialized.

Your definition of `s2` is actually equivalent to

```
char s2[] = { 'M', 'y', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'd', '\0' };
```

Answer (score 2):

s1 is only 9 by happenstance; you can only use strlen on terminated strings.  Declare it as char s1[] = { 'M', 'y', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'd', '\0' }; and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

strlen(s1) can return any value > 6. because he is searching for the first '\0' char and you didn't provide it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

- `s1` and `s2` are arrays of `char`.
- `s1` last element is `d`, whereas `s2` last element is `\0`.

That is, there is one more character in `s2`. It is a null-terminated string but `s1` is not a null-terminated string.

Since `s1` is not a null-terminated string, the expression `strlen(s1)` would invoke **undefined behavior**, as `strlen` will continue reading `s1` beyond the last element.